# Why can't I restart my maia service?

Tags: installation, command-line, postfix, mail-server

I have built a mail filtering server on Ubuntu 12.04 Server using Postfix, SpamAssassin, ClamAV, and Maia Mailguard by following this guide: 
http://www200.pair.com/mecham/spam/ubuntu1204-maia.html

It seems to be working OK except for one thing: I can't restart the maia service.

If I do `sudo service maia restart` I get:

```
Stopping maiad: (failed).
```

Same thing if I try the command `sudo /etc/init.d/maia restart`.

Also, I got an error last night when cron ran to rotate the logs:

`/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`:

```
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/maia/*.log '
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
```

If I check out `/etc/logrotate.d/maia` I can see that it too is trying to run `/etc/init.d/maia restart > /dev/null` which is where it is failing.

I thought maybe it is permissions so I tried restarting it as the `maia` user with:
`sudo su maia -c 'service maia restart'` but that got me the same `Stopping maiad: (failed).` error.

Any help would be appreciated; this seems to be the last thing preventing me from putting this box into production.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** Answered my own question. I hope this can help someone else with the same problem.

Comment: Sounds like the `maia` service itself has an error. Can you include it?

Comment: Please, show us the output of `# sh -x /etc/init.d/maia stop`

Comment: Could you add that as the answer instead of editing your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the `/etc/init.d/maia` script. This script is actually copied from the amavisd-new script, so eventually I found this: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/amavisd-new/1:2.6.5-0ubuntu3.1

Basically, remove the use of the --name flag when stopping the service. So, change:

`STOP="--stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name ${DAEMONNAME}"`

To:

`STOP="--stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE"`